# Disadvantage of Views in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Why Views are not used in widely in Drupal?

Comment: The premise of the question is false.  Views is the single most widely installed module, after Drupal core!  See the [usage statistics](http://drupal.org/project/usage) page.

Answer (score 2):

The question is so vague.

Disadvantage of using Views module? One of the disadvantages I can think of is its difficulty to configure it properly. Too many configurations needed to make things work.

p.s. this should move to Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question should really be "*why do some programmers discourage the use of Views in Drupal?*"

And the answer would be because of the massive amount of extra page overhead and extraneous markup that's generated by the module. Those of us who care about DOM complexity and semantic markup wouldn't touch Views with a 10 foot pole on a normal day, preferring to write quick custom modules to output code that we have full control over (and I mean full control without having to override countless template files for specific Views/display modes).

Don't get me wrong, Views is excellent for what it is and a newcomer to programming in Drupal would likely find it very useful. Also there are many, many contributed modules that extend Views and many that expose their data in a fashion accessible to Views so you can build some complex, well related queries if you know what you're doing.

I would also echo what Shivan Raptor has said in that the UI for Views is an unwieldy behemoth at the best of times; I'm sure to those who wrote it it's as easy as pie to use but I have been frustrated so many times trying to find how to make the simplest change to a View that I gave up using them altogether (except for Views provided by other modules that are already complete!)

So to summarise, your question's premise is indeed false, but if you wanted to know some of the reasons Views isn't *more* widely used then you do now :-)